# Picture beyond the layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am trying to make a layout that has got an image (green circle in the picture) that goes beyond the relative layout. Here is a picture:

[image: Example Image]

Any idea how to achieve such a thing in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open corresponding Xml file and add this Imageview after Relative Layout ..Like this..

```
<RootLayout>
<RelativeLayout >
</RelativeLayout>
<ImgView/>
</RootLayout>
```

u can test the behavior on Xml Graphical Layout itself.

issue here is that as soon as we add any view in xml , this is added in view container and container is Stack and hence the behavior!